# Google crawlers bringing my Drupal site down, anytime I visit Google Analytics

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

My Apache config for 32GB RAM and 4 CPUs at 2.4GHz:

Apache Config:

- **Prefork:**

  ```
  StartServers       8
  MinSpareServers    5
  MaxSpareServers   20
  ServerLimit      300
  MaxClients       150
  MaxRequestsPerChild  4500
  ```
- **Worker:**

  ```
  StartServers         4
  MaxClients         200
  MinSpareThreads     25
  MaxSpareThreads     75
  ThreadsPerChild     25
  MaxRequestsPerChild  0
  ```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, figure out why Drupal's crashing. If crawlers can take you down easily, so can malicious users. Fix the **problem**, not the symptom.

Comment: First of all you should figure out which of the prefork or threaded MPMs you are using and remove the config for the other one from your question.  I suspect you're using the prefork MPM as that's the most common choice for PHP deployments.  Next, figure out what resource limit your site is hitting when it goes down - RAM, CPU, MaxClients, disk access, MySQL connections, open files, etc.  Most of these have nothing to do with the config you have posted.  Once you know what resource it is, change your question to something like "How can I make Drupal use less RAM?"

Comment: @ladadadada The MaxClients keeps reaching the limit, I increased it from 50 to 150